# Select and Show N=50 records per page from MySQL Table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I am working on a script that queries a MySQL database to show all records in a table. In the past I have got a working solution with procedural code, but now I would like to use PDO and a class (a sort of PDO wrapper I have defined). For some reason, I do not see anything, the page is loaded successfully, but no table and no data is shown...I get no error message as well though. Any help in debugging the following code would be greatly appreciated. In particular, I would like to know how to debug PDO in such a situation. 
Here it is the list_patients script:

```
<?php

// Ok. Let's define the page title, dynamically: see config.inc.php for details
$page_title = 'Kardia: Patients List';

// First --> Let us then include info regarding the connection to the database, PHP functions, and header section and page title

require('../../includes/config.inc.php');
require('../../includes/class.dataBase.php');
require('../../includes/functions.php');
require('../elements/layouts/header.php');

// Second --> Let's 'Check whether user has the rights to see current page or not

if(!isLoggedIn()) //"isLoggedIn" is a pre-specified function in functions.php file
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
}

// Number of records to show per page:

$display = 50;

try  {

// Determine how many pages there are...
if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) { // Already been determined. p = pages

    $pages = $_GET['p'];

} else { // Need to determine.

    // Count the number of records:

    $db = new dataBase(); // istantiate a new object (db) from the class Database
    // Run the query to count number of records in the demographics table


    $stmt = $db -> execute('SELECT COUNT(PID) FROM `demographics`;');



    // setting the fetch mode


    $row = $stmt-> single(PDO::FETCH_NUM);



    $records = $row[0];



    // Calculate the number of pages...
    if ($records > $display) { // More than 1 page.
        $pages = ceil ($records/$display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;
    }

} // End of p IF.

// Determine where in the database to start returning results...
if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])) {
    $start = $_GET['s'];
} else {
    $start = 0;
}

// Determine the sort order...
// Default is by registration date.
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'RECRUIT_TS';

// Determine the sorting order:
switch ($sort) {
    case 'name':
        $order_by = 'LASTNAME ASC';
        break;
    case 'dob':
        $order_by = 'DOB ASC';
        break;
    case 'disease_1':
        $order_by = 'DISEASE_1 ASC';
        break;
    case 'ADDRESS':
        $order_by = 'ADDRESS ASC';
        break;
    case 'city':
        $order_by = 'CITY ASC';
        break;
    case 'phone_1':
        $order_by = 'PHONE_1 ASC';
        break;
    case 'email_1':
        $order_by = 'EMAIL_1 ASC';
        break;  
    default:
        $order_by = 'RECRUIT_TS ASC';
        $sort = 'RECRUIT_TS';
        break;
}


// Make the query to build the table subsequently:



$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(LASTNAME, ', ', FIRSTNAME) AS name,
             DATE_FORMAT(DOB,'%M-%d-%Y') AS dob,
             DATE_FORMAT(RECRIT_TS,'%M-%d-%Y') AS reg_date,
             DISEASE_1 as disease,
             ADDRESS as ADDRESS,
             CITY as city,
             PHONE_1 as phone,
             EMAIL_1 as email,
             PID
      FROM `demographics`
      ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start, $display";

$result = $db->single($sql);


// Count the number of returned rows:
    $num = $db->rowCount($result);

    if ($num > 0) { // If it ran OK, display the records.




echo '

// Table header. Here the names of the fields have to be reported as they really are (so recruit_d remain recruit_d NOT reg_date)

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "http://10.0.0.1/public/css/tables.css" media="screen, tv, projection" title="Default" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "http://10.0.0.1/public/css/forms.css" media="screen, tv, projection" title="Default" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "http://10.0.0.1/public/css/validation.css" media="screen, tv, projection" title="Default" />

<body>
    <div id="header" class="full">   
         <h1>List of Patients</h1>
            <div id="inner_header" class="centered">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php">Demographics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#hp_php">History-Physical</a></li>
                <li><a href="#biomark.php">Biomarkers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ecg.php">ECG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#echo.php">ECHO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ct_rmn.php">CT-RMN</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br class="clear" />&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>


    <body>
    ';

    // Print how many users there are:
    echo "<p>There are currently <strong>$num</strong> patients in the DataBase.</p>\n";

    echo '
    <div id="table">
    <table align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Details/Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=name">Name</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=dob">Date of Birth</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=recruit_d">Date Registered</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=disease_1">Primary Disease</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=ADDRESS">Address</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=city">City</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=phone_1">Phone Number</a></th>
        <th><a href="list_patients.php?sort=email_1">Email</a></th>
    </tr>
            ';

// Fetch and print all the records....

 $bg = 'transparent'; // Set the initial background color.

        while($row = $db->single(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


     $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee'); // Switch the background color (Ternary Operator).

     // Be CAREFULL HERE: you have to report the fields with the names defined in the AS part of the query NOT their real names !
     // so "recruit_d" becomes "reg_date", disease_1 simply disease, etc... 
     // Besides, pay attention on the occurrence of <a href="edit_patient.php?id=' . $row['pid'] . '" --> This define the $id var 
     // used later on to Update or Delete the patient !  
        echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
            <td align="left"><a href="edit_patient.php?id=' . $row['pid'] . '" 
                              style="background-color: transparent; color: #4169E1; font-weight: 700";>Details-Edit</a></td>
            <td align="left"><a href="delete_patient.php?id=' . $row['pid'] . '"
                              style="background-color: transparent; color: #4169E1; font-weight: 700";>Delete</a></td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['name'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['dob'] . '</td> 
            <td align="left">' . $row['reg_date'] . '</td> 
            <td align="left">' . $row['disease'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['ADDRESS'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['city'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['email'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    } // End of WHILE loop

    echo '
        </table>
    </div>
            ';




// Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
if ($pages >= 1) {

    echo '<br /><p>';
    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    // If it's not the first page, make a Previous button:
    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="list_patients.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    // Make all the numbered pages:
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="list_patients.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    } // End of FOR loop.

    // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="list_patients.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>'; // Close the paragraph.


    } else { // If it did not run OK.



    } // End of links section.




} // End of if $num > 0 IF

 } catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo '<p class="error"> An Error Occurred: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>'; // Report the Error

}
?>
<?php
    // Let us  include the footer
    require_once '../elements/layouts/footer.php';
    exit();
?>
```

And this is the class.DataBase I have defined as PDO wrapper

```
class dataBase extends PDO{
    private $host      = 'localhost';
    private $user      = 'root';
    private $pass      = '';
    private $dbname    = 'kardia';
    private $port      = '3306';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';port' . $this->port;
        // Set options (i.e. set PDO Attrbutes, to define what exceptions to catch)
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instance
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
            // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = '<p class="error"> An Error Occurred: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
        }
    }
    // let us define the stmt attribute
        private $stmt;

        public function query($sql){
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        }

        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
            if (is_null($type)) {
                switch (true) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);

        }

        public function execute(){
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }

        public function resultset(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public function single(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public function rowCount(){
            return $this->stmt->rowCount();
        }

        public function lastId(){
            return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }

        public function debugDumpParams(){
            return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with this code and the style it is written in.

To answer your question on debugging things, use print_r($data) and var_dump($data) where $data is anything you want to know the value of.

Also, you don't need to echo everything. You can put HTML inside a PHP file and it will still render as HTML providing it is not inside  tags. For example:

```
<?php 
// your PHP code
?>

<strong>Some HTML table code here.</strong>

<?php 
// more PHP code here
?>
```

I would begin with scrapping all of your table and HTML code and just make sure you get relevant data out of a database using your database class and printing the results in PHP using `print_r($data);`

Then I would look at getting that into working HTML.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply and for the advices. I have separated HTML and PHP, getting rid of those echo '' sentences, and I have also tried to print_r different variables...still, I get the header, then a blank page. Finally, I have tested the SQL queries manually and there are no errors,but I cannot see anything in the screen yet....

Comment: If you just see white below the header, perhaps you are not logged in? How far down your script does it all work until? Do you have PHP errors turned on? If not, put this at the top of your code: 
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: Nope...the script is in page that runs only after successful login procedure (that is completed correctly) and Excdeptions are turned on in teh config file (I have not reported that here for brevity). Apparently this construct is creating problems: $stmt = $db -> execute('SELECT COUNT(PID) FROM `demographics`;'); and although the query runs Ok in PHPMyAdmin...the script stops here...is maybe something wrong with this command and the class ?

Comment: Please ensure you have full error reporting on. I have tried your dataBase class and using it with a basic query in my test db and it errors: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\euler\17\index.php on line 58

Comment: Also you have syntax errors. $stmt = $db -> should be $stmt = $db->  you do not put spaces in between $db and ->.

Comment: Thank you very much ! As you suggested, the PDO statement was incorrect (and still is...but at least the script goes on now, and I get a lot of errors I have to analyze :) unfortunately I have really got to go, but will work on that tonight...again, thank you so much :)